# Question about converting Mma expressions to TeX

Tags: programming, latex

When I want to convert the following expression

```
Integrate[1/(1 + t (-I - 1)) (-I - 1), {t, 0, 1}]
```

to TeX, I do:

```
HoldForm[Integrate[1/(1 + t (-I - 1)) (-I - 1), {t, 0, 1}]] // TeXForm
```

which works fine.

Now, I want to do the same without having to add HoldForm. I thought that the following might work.

```
tex[exp_] := TeXForm[HoldForm[exp]]

Integrate[1/(1 + t (-I - 1)) (-I - 1), {t, 0, 1}] //tex
```

Sadly, this does not work.

Is there a way to make this work?

Update:
Just found out that //HoldForm //TeXForm works as well at end of line. But how to shorten that?

Comment: Add `SetAttributes[tex,HoldFirst]` and your `tex` function will work.

Comment: It does! Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome!